# Kafka - java clients comparison

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I want to use Kafka in my java program. Which of kafka java clients is best for which usecase? Can you point me differences between Kafka Streams, Kafka Connect and Kafka Spring (and others if they exists)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the simple use cases I would use the standard Kafka Clients from the Kafka distribution: Kafka Producer and Kafka Consumer. It would be enough to write simple applications.

If you want to build complex stream processing apps on top of Kafka - the Kafka Streams library is the best choice. With Kafka Streams you will be able to build very complex apps similar to Spark Streaming (with filter, map, flatMap etc functions).

Kafka Connect is a way to import/export data to/from Kafka. For instance with Kafka ElasticSearch-Connector you will be able to export your data from your Kafka topics to ElasticSearch directly and in real time.

1. Kafka Connect: https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/x
2. Kafka Streams: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/
3. Kafka Clients: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/0.11.0.0

Comment: If I want to read from kafka and save do DB after transformation, where is difference between `Kafka Stream` and listener consumer from `spring kafka`?

Comment: @ByeBye I am not familiar with Kafka Spring, sorry. But I assume, Kafka Spring is basically a Spring wrapper on top of Kafka client. For your use case I would suggest the following scenario:

Input Kafka topic => KafkaStreams App doing your transformation => output Kafka topic => Kafka JDBC-Sink connector => DB